# Writing text mode screen to a text file. (MASM)

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16, vga

Basically I have to create a maze and store it in a text file so I can open it up later, I already have the creating the maze part down but I for the life of me can't get it to save everything that's on screen to a text file (even the blank spaces) I know i can use int 21h to write things to a file I just don't know how to write everything to said text file (the whole 80 lines and 25 columns) in the order are displayed on the dosbox screen.

```
mov     ah,3CH ; File creation
mov     cx,0    ; 
mov     dx, OFFSET filename
int     21h
mov     handle, ax

mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax
ciclo2:
    mov ah, es:[bx]
    mov al, es:[bx+1]
    mov var1, ax
    mov ah,40h
    mov cx,2
    mov dx,var1
    mov bx,handle
    int 21h
    inc bx
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 4000
    jne ciclo2
fim:
    mov     ah,3Eh ; Closing the file
    mov     bx,handle
    int     21h

    mov     ah,4CH ; Closing the program
    INT     21H
```

I'm using MASM and dosBOX.

Comment: What is the problem or what is the wrong result that you get?

Comment: It's supposed to write what's on the screen to a txt file but it ends up not printing anything at all.

Comment: I found 4 errors in your code, check the answer below (if it's useful don't forget to click on the ✔ checkmark of the answer).

Comment: Your code is writing the character and the attribute to the file. Is that what you have to do? Or do you just need to store the character in the text file?

Answer (score 1):

Next are 4 errors in your code snippet and the fixes :

```
mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax
xor si,si     ;◄■■ INITIALIZE SI = 0.
ciclo2:
    mov aL, es:[si]    ;◄■■ CHARACTER IN AL.
    mov aH, es:[si+1]  ;◄■■ COLOR IN AH.
    mov var1, ax
    mov ah,40h
    mov cx,2
;   mov dx,var1       ;◄■■ WRONG : VARIABLE VALUE.
    lea dx,var1       ;◄■■ RIGHT : VARIABLE ADDRESS.
    mov bx,handle
    int 21h
    inc si
    inc si
    cmp si, 4000
    jne ciclo2
fim:
```

When you read the file to display the content, remember the screen contains the character first (`mov al, es:[si]`) and the color later (`mov ah, es:[si+1]`), display the bytes in that order, or you will see strange characters and colors on screen.

Comment: I just realized that this code puts me in an infinite loop since bx keeps getting changed to the value in "handle" in order to use int 21h , is there any other register I can use instead of bx for this part 

    mov al, es:[bx]
    mov ah, es:[bx+1]

Comment: @GabrielSilva, I replaced `BX` by `SI`, this register will do the job.

Comment: `mov ax, es:[si]` would load both AL and AH with a single instruction.  But this still looks really inefficient, @GabrielSilva: why not just point DS at video RAM and make one larger write call, instead of copying 2 bytes at a time to a tiny buffer?  For some reason you're writing both bytes (character + color/attribute), so it's not really just a text file, it's a complete dump of video RAM to a file, 2 bytes at a time.